# Delete a folder in my home screen Android 4.0, Aquos?

Tags: home-screen-folders

My home screen looks like this:

```
Empty_folder | Application 1 | Application 2 | Application N
```

When I long press over the folder, I have the option to rename it.  How do I delete the folder, though?  I've been moving them to a different screen, but now I have three screens of blank folders that I accidentally created by trying to rearrange icons.

Also, I wonder how do I switch two icons on my home screen?  When I drag two items into each other, they don't switch but rather create a folder and then add themselves to it, which seems ridiculous.  In any other OS, if I want a new folder, I have to be very specific about that.

Comment: You could say that in any other OS you have to do something obscure and not easily discoverable to create a folder. Android just works out that if you're dragging one icon on top of another you're trying to fit more than one in that space and just automatically creates a folder for you.

Comment: @gathrawn I agree.  It's a little annoying when people talk about "the true linux way" to me, also, so....  Sorry if it came off like a rage.  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press and hold the folder, one of the home icons will turn into a trash icon. Just drag the folder to the trash icon.

Answer (score 2):

If you long press over something in the Aquos, "Peel off" is used to remove it.